# How to model a decimal response between 0 to 1 with a GLM in R

Tags: r, predictive-modeling, glm

I am trying to model a response variable which is a proportion (so a response between 0 and 1, see picture for distribution).

Ideally I would like to model it without using the actual counts, so as a decimal.

So far I have been using a binomial family in R.

```
model <- glm(Response ~ 
                X1 +
                X2 + 
                X3,
              data = Training_data,
              family = 'binomial')
```

I think the model is doing okay, but when I use it for predictions it doesn't do a good job predicting when the ratio is 1 (As you can see from the picture).

I'm not sure if my approach of using a binomial distribution is wrong?

Thanks for your help [image: ![Distribution of actual response and predicted response]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFKmy.png)

Comment: This is not completely off topic, but in my opinion you will get better answers to that question in cross validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks, I just posted there.